# (Flask-)SQLAlchemy primary key issues probably due to implicit transactions

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In a project using Flask-SQLAlchemy, i get some intermittent errors and i think it might be due to not explicitly using transactions.

I have these two model classes, one for locations and another for closures:

```
class Location(db.Model):
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String)
    code = sa.Column(sa.String, unique=True)


class LocationPath(db.Model):
    ancestor_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    descendant_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('location.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    depth = sa.Column(sa.Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
```

In a background process, i'm doing a lot of inserts, so i'm bypassing the ORM to use Core:

```
location_table = Location.__table__
location_path_table = LocationPath.__table__

statement = select([location_table.c.id]).where(code == code)
result = db.session.get_bind().execute(statement)
location_id = result.first()

if location_id is None:
    statement = location_table.insert().values(**kwargs)
    result = db.session.get_bind().execute(statement)
    new_id = result.inserted_primary_key[0]
    result.close()
else:
    new_id = location_id
# save new_id as an ancestor_id or a descendant_id

path = LocationPath.query.filter_by(
    ancestor_id=ancestor_id,
    descendant_id=descendant_id
).first()
if path is None:
    statement = location_path_table.insert().values(
        ancestor_id=ancestor_id,
        descendant_id=descendant_id,
        depth=depth)
    # the line below intermittently generates either of two errors:
    # - the inserted primary key (ancestor/descendant) does not exist
    # - a duplicate key error where the path already exists
    result = db.session.get_bind().execute(statement)
```

this has resulted in quite a bit of head-scratching on my part, since i get the `ancestor_id` or `descendant_id` either from a `select` or an `insert`, and i also query the database to see if the path exists before attempting to insert it.

**Edit:** the code above runs in a loop.

Comment: can you check if result.lastrowid is the same as result.inserted_primary_key[0] ? seems a bit suspect to me

Comment: you're also filtering LocationPath by both the ancestor and descendant_id - is it possible you need an _or here, so it will find results that only apply to one of those? if its finds no results, it will try inserting one which could have an id which already exists (for one of two)